# Error 419 page expired after login - Laravel - Windows server 2012 R2

Tags: php, laravel, windows-server-2012-r2

I created one project in Laravel 5.8.32, in my local enviroment I have PHP(7.2.28) and its work fine, when I hosted the project on windows server with PHP 7.2.7 after login its return 419 | page expired error.

I have been make every recommendation that I found on internet, for example:
I have `@csrf` on my login form like this:

```
<form action="{{ route('login) }} method='POST'>
@csrf
....
</form>
```

also tried with `{{ csrf_field }}`.

I cleaned the cache whit `php artisan config:cache && php artisan cache:clear && php artisan optimize`

I updated the folder permissions to:

```
777 storage
777 vendor
777 bootstrap/cache
```

also Laravel session settings with:

```
'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),
'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),
```

I generated a new key application `php artisan key:generate`.

but no one of this recommendations works form me, so someone can help me with other way?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have the right permission for **storage/framework/sessions** ?

Comment: yes, I updated the folder permissions for every folder in storage